# Как перекодировать UTF-16 в UTF-32 на делфи?

Tags: delphi, utf

Какой функцией перекодировать UTF-16 в UTF-32.

Comment: System.Character.TCharacter.ConvertToUtf32

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая функция [System.UnicodeStringToUCS4String](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UnicodeStringToUCS4String):

```
function UnicodeStringToUCS4String(const S: UnicodeString): UCS4String;
```

> Converts a Unicode string to its UCS-4 encoded representation.
>
> Call UnicodeStringToUCS4String to convert a Unicode string to its
>   UCS-4 encoded representation. S is a Unicode string that contains
>   UTF-16 characters. The result of the function is the corresponding
>   UCS-4 string value.